# How to zip operations on nummpy arrays where conditional filter needs to be applied only on one of them

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2d nummpy array something like this:

```
(array([[7.948829 , 3.7127783, 3.6365926, 3.4607997]], dtype=float32),
 array([[ 5, 15,  7, 39]]))
```

The first array in this array are distances and the second is indices, I want to know if there is a way I could filter the first array based on a certain threshold and then also delete the corresponding indices from the index?

Comment: Welcome to SO and writing code.
If you want people to help you, I'd advise you to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your posts.
Another thing that will help people is refraining from including useless information in your question like "The first array in this array are distances and the second is indices". this line has nothing to do with the actual question and just stands to potentially confuse people or just waste their time. A clean question is a great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([7.948829 , 3.7127783, 3.6365926, 3.4607997])
b = np.array([ 5, 15,  7, 39])
c = b[a>3.7]
d = a[a>3.7]
print(f'c = \n{c}')
print(f'd = \n{d}')
```

output:

```
c = 
[ 5 15]
d = 
[7.948829  3.7127783]
```